# Live action TV show where High school Kids go into the virtual world and have to clear levels

Tags: story-identification, tv

I've been trying to remember this live action TV show for years now.

In it teenagers were able to enter this virtual world of sorts and they become these avatars. Their goal was to clear levels and move on to the next and I don't remember why. There were artifacts or items that help them on their way and they can return to the real world easily enough. I think they can re-enter the virtual world through someone's school.

To pinpoint a possible date I'm thinking maybe 2000s to 2004s, it is hard to remember because I was so young.

Comment: You have a nice start here but could you look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, you say _"years ago"_ but do you remember roughly how many years ago that was?

Comment: If this was a gameshow, it could be "Virtually Impossible". But the Code Lyoko answer below looks like a better fit, to be honest.

Comment: Reminds me of some show with an alien-ish girl who tastes through her fingertips?

Comment: @AJM - [Nick Arcade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Arcade) came to mind for me.

Comment: so answer you TheLethalCarrot im thinking it was in 2000s maybe 2004s all i know was i was super young

Comment: If you had said the 1990s I would have said [knightmare](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knightmare)

Comment: yeah sadly kightmare isn't it but it might be later then the 2000s i remember it looking pretty good but anyway thanks for your input Matt Ellen

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It was the 2004 show on YTV called *Zixx Level One*.

> Two brothers discover an alien girl called Zixx Punkee Zee and help her get past level one of a game. When Zixx finishes all three levels she will have achieved her mission and be able to go back to her home world.
>
> <sub>[IMDb, Zixx Level One](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0348979/?ref_=ttmi_t)</sub>

[image]

Comment: Thank you to everyone who help me find this And Special Thanks to malady for giving me an better idea where to look with hes Live Action English Language show about a virtual world with an human-appearing girl who tastes orange juice through her fingertips? post really help me out thanks Bro

Comment: :) Don't forget to self accept in another day or so.

Comment: Wow, those graphics really are 2004, I think I played games that looked as good as that back then, never mind pre-rendered stuff!

Comment: Good find!  Your question sounded really familiar to me, but when I last looked at the answers none of them really rung a bell in the way I was expecting.  This is definitely the show I was thinking of.  Probably somewhat niche since it only seems to have had a couple seasons aired in Canada.

Answer (score 15):

If *years ago* means four of five years, it could be *Code Lyoko Evolution*.

[image: Code lyoko evolution poster]

Code Lyoko is originatly a french cartoon where a group of teenagers find a computer in which lives XANA, a powerfull virus able to make changements in the real world. Fortunately, they are able to go inside the digital world to beat XANA at its source. The part inside the digital world is in CGI, where the parts in the real world is drawn. Inside lives Aelita, a friendly AI that helps them to understand the world. This cartoon went out in the year 2000.

In 2012, they made a sequel in live action, called *Code Lyoko Evolution*. The parts in the real world are now live action, and the part in the digital world are still in CGI. The main characters are now highschoolers.

Here's a [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Lyoko:_Evolution).

Comment: I though about giving the same answer. But does Code Lyoko go out of the french territory ?

Comment: @TinyDoowy *Code Lyoko*, in cartoon, went out of France, it was even available on US Netflix 'til 2015. According to Wikipedia, *Code Lyoko Evolution* was diffused in France, Belgium, Hungary and Serbia. There is a date of diffusion for the fifth episode for the US, but the reference seems to be outdated.

Comment: There's no particular notion of level-clearing though, neither in CL or CLE. Unless one counts deactivating a tower as "clearing" a level... But meh. Though if we're being honest, _Code Lyoko Evolution_ would have needed a **lot** of clearing, on several levels...

Comment: Sorry but Code Lyoko Evolution is not it but thanks for the input

Comment: The cartoon was also syndicated on Cartoon Network (dubbed in English) many years ago (and maybe they're still doing it for all I know). @Jenayah: They didn't "clear levels" per se, but deactivating towers is pretty analogous. And in season 3, there was quite a bit of "clearing" of things...

Comment: I recognized the similarity to Code Lyoko from the title, but was confused about the "live-action" part. I didn't even know this was a thing.

Answer (score 8):

If the TV show you are thinking of was from the 90s and had a similar look and feel to Power Rangers, then you might be thinking of [*VR Troopers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VR_Troopers).

> The show focused on three teenagers in their late teens, Ryan Steele, Kaitlin Star, and J.B. Reese, living in the fictional West Coast town of Cross World City, California. They regularly attended and were teachers at "Tao's Dojo," a karate studio. Ryan was the most focused martial artist; J.B. was the computer wizard; while Kaitlin was a photographer & budding reporter for the local newspaper, the Underground Voice Daily. One day, Ryan's search for his long-missing father led him and his two friends to a strange laboratory. Inside, a digitized head of Professor Horatio Hart (who is a friend of Ryan's father Tyler) explained the truth about his life's work of having developed extremely advanced virtual reality technology in secret. "VR" is a dimension existing alongside our own; within it lie mutants bent on conquering both worlds. The main ruler of these is a creature known as Grimlord, who, unbeknownst to anyone on Earth, has a human identity as billionaire industrialist Karl Ziktor. As Karl Ziktor tries to overcome the barriers of the true reality to allow his armies easy passage from virtual world, the responsibility falls to Ryan, Kaitlin, and J.B. of defending the planet on both sides of the dimensional barrier. They have assistance in the form of armored bodies having incredible firepower. This included eventual additions to their arsenal, such as a Turbo Cycle, Techno Bazooka, VR Troopertron, VR Shoulder Cannon, VR Battlecruiser/Interceptop and a flying, laser-blasting Skybase.

Comment: Sorry but VR Troopers isn't it

Answer (score 3):

This could also match with [*ReBoot: The Guardian Code*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReBoot:_The_Guardian_Code), the *ReBoot* reboot, except for that being a bit too recent (although it was announced in 2013, it wasn't released until 2018, a little less than a year ago).

> Four teenaged gamers, who are members of an online game's highest-scoring team, meet in person on their first day at Alan Turing High School. Their enrollment was arranged by Vera, an artificial intelligence who has recruited the team as "Guardians" to physically enter and protect cyberspace. Early in the series, Vera is given a human body and locked out of cyberspace, so she enrolls as an exchange student. The Guardians battle the Sourcerer, a human hacker . Dark code is the Sourcerer's primary weapon against the world's computer systems. After his initial run-in with the Guardians, the Sourcerer reactivates the computer virus named Megabyte, the main antagonist of the original ReBoot, to help him from inside cyberspace.

### Trailer

Comment: The question is about something they've been searching for "for years now", and this answer is about a TV show which first aired last year.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I was seeing the 2013 figure for it, but it didn't get released until 2018. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: I was thinking the original show, but that probably aired way too long ago.

Answer (score 3):

There is a show similar to what you describe.
The Super Human Samurai Cyber Squad had 3 teens enter a virtual world where they fought various creatures. 3 Robots, with 2 of them joining to the Humanoid like character to form 2 different super fighters. The toys were like transformers and expensive/large.

Comment: nope thats not it thanks for your input tho

Answer (score 3):

Your description made me think of [*Video Game High School*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Game_High_School) which is around 5-7 years old (released in 2012). It is a live action series that does involve virtual worlds and a school but not avatars as far as I can recall.

Comment: no thats not it sorry but thanks for your input

Answer (score 3):

This is a movie not a TV show, but in [Spy Kids 3-D: Game Over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spy_Kids_3-D:_Game_Over) (released 2003) the kids enter a virtual game world and have to work their way through 5 levels of the game.

Trailer:

Comment: its 100% not Spy Kids 3-D and i was 100% waiting for someone to say this movie lol but thanks for your input anyway

Comment: Haha no worries :)

Answer (score 2):

Could it by any chance be the 1992 game show [*Nick Arcade*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Arcade)? You might be thinking of the video zone portion of the show.

> The Video Zone was actually a live-action video game with three levels. Using a video monitor to see themselves, the contestants would be backstage, climbing ladders, throwing "snowballs", and using a boat in front of a bluescreen attempting to achieve previously explained goals (which was always to obtain three objects) for each level of the game.

Comment: nope sorry thanks for the input tho. i remember the show having a plot but for the life of me i cant remember it

Answer (score 1):

The original [*ReBoot*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108903/) matches the description and the timespan you describe.

> In the inner computer world of Mainframe, a guardian program sprite and his friends defend the system from threats from viruses and the User.

Comment: Could you [edit] this to explain _how_ it matches the OP's description? Though note the OP has already found the work they were looking for.