# Live Action English Language show about a virtual world with an human-appearing girl who tastes orange juice through her fingertips?

Tags: story-identification, tv

Live Action English Language show about a virtual world with an human-appearing girl who tastes orange juice through her fingertips?

And she's not human, but might be under a hologram? ... I think she might have blue skin??

She never had orange juice before, or didn't know what it was, and another character covered for her strangeness, I think.

And I think it might be the answer the same show that "[Live action TV show where High school Kids go into the virtual world and have to clear levels](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/213991/live-action-tv-show-where-high-school-kids-go-into-the-virtual-world-and-have-to)" is trying to find.

And it was broadcast in Canada during the 2000s, on Teletoon, Family Channel, or YTV?

That's all I remember.

Comment: Are you saying that you think it's the same show?

Comment: @Valorum - Possibly, yes. Adding.

Comment: The part about tasting orange juice through her fingertips sounds familiar but I can't think why.

Comment: @F1Krazy - She put it in a glass, and her weirdness was hidden...

Comment: It doesn't fit the gender, or the virtual world, but this strikes me as the sort of thing Ax from Animorphs might do, him being obsessed with the taste of human foodstuffs, and his natural Alexis absorbing food through their hooves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for a 2004 show on YTV called *Zixx Level One*. It was also the answer to [my question here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/214077/58193).

> Two brothers discover an alien girl called Zixx Punkee Zee and help her get past level one of a game. When Zixx finishes all three levels she will have achieved her mission and be able to go back to her home world.
>
> <sub>[IMDb, Zixx Level One](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0348979/?ref_=ttmi_t)</sub>

[image]

Comment: Congrats on finding it! ... How did you do it?

Comment: you actually help me.when you posted with this post when you said Canadian and could be on YTV. so i look up old ytv shows on the Internet and i look at list of old ytv shows until the picture for this one lol so Familiar i knew this was it